# Dropdown Menu of bootstrap doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dropdown menu with responsive feature but the dropdown menu does not work when I click on them then nothing is open here is the code

```
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggel" data-toggel="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">RG_ACADEMY</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggel"  data-toggel="dropdown" href="#">About us <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">About Academy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Faculty Team</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggel" data-toggel="dropdown" href="#">Courses <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS+ADVANCED</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

  </nav>
```

and the output is [image] and also the sign I do not understand why it is the show

Comment: Check developer's console for errors...

Comment: Check for errors and Also can you reproduce the issue in JsFiddle?

Comment: `navbar-toggel` this classname is spelled wrong - should be `navbar-toggle`.

Comment: Also the couple instances of `dropdown-toggel`...

Comment: I just add scripts of <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js"></script>

    <script src="twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: the symbol problem is solved but the dropdown still can't work

Comment: spelling of toggle

Answer (score 2):

Just fix your spelling.  Bootstrap can't target your classes correctly if they're spelled wrong.  Bootstrap uses the spelling `toggle`, not `toggel` -

```
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">RG_ACADEMY</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About us <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">About Academy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Faculty Team</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

          <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Courses <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS+ADVANCED</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works. Your error is that you mis-spelled `toggle` to `toggel` everywhere in your code. Correct that and it all works perfectly fine.

```
<nav>
 <div>
<div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">RG_ACADEMY</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About us <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">About Academy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Faculty Team</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Courses <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS+ADVANCED</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

  </nav>
```

Include bootstrap classes along with jquery.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/06sknc2o/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in the code "toggel is TOGGLE" for example.

It does not make you add functionality javascript should bootstrap the catch automatically if you have well the call to your JS

[Example dropdown menu](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=dropdowns-within-navbar)

Answer (score 0):

Try This code for your problem

```
<script src="content/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="content/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change : `dropdown-toggel` to `dropdown-toggle` and `data-toggel="dropdown"` to `data-toggle="dropdown"`

Partially corrected output : [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/BSroZO0QId#)

Answer (score -2):

**try this before body:**

```
<script>
     $(function () {
       $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
     }); 
</script>
```

Comment: This is not necessary, and the classname is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: now dropdown is work but after that, when I was click on the button then it is not hide

Comment: The scripts I used earlier is it necessary or I can remove that one?